# How To Combine/Pull corresponding Columns

Tags: sql

I have the following table in SQL

[image]

I would like to create a new table that combines the values of FemaleID and MaleID into one column FemaleMale, while bringing in the corresponding columns as well.

Here would be the final output.

[image]

How can this be done? I am using snowflake.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you are using Snowflake, then tag Snowflake, instead of completely different database products, MySQL & SQL Server - which are totally not relevant.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Without answers to questions asked in comments, this might need changing, but general SQL, this is simple UNION:

```
SELECT FemaleId AS FemaleMale, Stage, Season 
FROM YourTable

UNION ALL

SELECT MaleId AS FemaleMale, Stage, Season
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I tried this and have values from Stage in season and season to Stage